Kohen saying the Nasi
From the begining of Nissan we say the daily nassi. This includes kohanim and leviim even though their tribe isn't one of the tribes that brought sacrifices.
Why do they say it and why do they say the yehi ratzon incase they are from a certain tribe?

Can you source that this exists before asking for an explanation thereof?

https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/3316084/jewish/1-Nissan-Rosh-Chodesh.htm

Some say a kohen/levi should not recite the yehi ratzon
